# Extract week and day from an xts object into a column

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I would like to get the week and day of an xts object. I tried to extract the index value of my data set (based on SPY data using `quantmod` package) without success. How could I do this?

```
 require(quantmod)
 options(scipen=999)
 spy<-getSymbols(("SPY") , src = 'yahoo', from = '2007-01-01',  auto.assign = T)
 tail(SPY)          
 SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
2016-01-22   189.78   190.76  188.88    190.52  163849600       190.52
2016-01-25   189.92   190.15  187.41    187.64  122676200       187.64
2016-01-26   188.42   190.53  188.02    190.20  137269900       190.20
2016-01-27   189.58   191.56  187.06    188.13  181677100       188.13
2016-01-28   189.96   190.20  187.16    189.11  139970600       189.11
2016-01-29   190.02   193.88  189.88    193.72  195455400       193.72
 SPY$Date<-as.Date(index(SPY))
 tail(SPY)
           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume   Date
2016-01-22   189.78   190.76  188.88    190.52  163849600 190.52
2016-01-25   189.92   190.15  187.41    187.64  122676200 187.64
2016-01-26   188.42   190.53  188.02    190.20  137269900 190.20
2016-01-27   189.58   191.56  187.06    188.13  181677100 188.13
2016-01-28   189.96   190.20  187.16    189.11  139970600 189.11
2016-01-29   190.02   193.88  189.88    193.72  195455400 193.72

 SPY$Date<-as.character(index(SPY))
 tail(SPY)
           SPY.Open     SPY.High     SPY.Low      SPY.Close    SPY.Volume  Date        
2016-01-22 "189.779999" "190.759995" "188.880005" "190.520004" "163849600" "2016-01-22"
2016-01-25 "189.919998" "190.149994" "187.410004" "187.639999" "122676200" "2016-01-25"
2016-01-26 "188.419998" "190.529999" "188.020004" "190.199997" "137269900" "2016-01-26"
2016-01-27 "189.580002" "191.559998" "187.059998" "188.130005" "181677100" "2016-01-27"
2016-01-28 "189.960007" "190.199997" "187.160004" "189.110001" "139970600" "2016-01-28"
2016-01-29 "190.020004" "193.880005" "189.880005" "193.720001" "195455400" "2016-01-29"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.indexwday` to get the weekday of the index. It returns the `wday` vector from a `POSIXlt` representation of the index, so see the *Details* section of `?POSIXlt` for a description.

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY")
SPY$weekday <- .indexwday(SPY)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
week_days <- weekdays(index(SPY))
```

To add these weekdays as a column in your xts object, try *twice*

```
SPY$SPY.week_days <- week_days
```

The first attempt will generate a warning message and create a new column full of `NA`s, the second attempt will fill that new column correctly. There's certainly a cleaner way, but it's a quick fix that should work.

However, as pointed out by @nrussell, this converts the entire data into characters, so you will have to use `as.numeric()` to extract the OHLC values. Or, as @nrussell suggested, use a data.frame instead.

The week of the year can be obtained with:

```
library(lubridate)
SPY$SPY.week <- week(index(SPY))
```

Since `week()` yields a numeric vector, you won't have any difficulty adding this one as a column to your xts object. That is in contrast to the character output of `weekdays()`, which entails the problems discussed above.

Comment: Thank  i applied this line of code SPY$week_days <- weekdays(index(SPY))
but got all the figures as characters,How can I evoid it?

Comment: You can't have numeric and character in a matrix. Use a `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code you suggested a bit so here are my lines of code based on your idea: week_days <- weekdays(index(SPY));
 SPY <- as.data.frame(unclass(SPY));
 SPY<-cbind(SPY,week_days)

Comment: Looks good. But why do you use `unclass()`? I think you could just go with `SPY <- as.data.frame(SPY)`.